# python selenium saved image empty

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium module in python. I am trying to load image and  save it locally. For that I am using following code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.execute_script("window.open()" )
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get("http://media.santabanta.com/medium1/cricket/trent%20boult/trent-boult-0a.jpg")
driver.save_screenshot('im1.jpg')
```

The problem I am getting is the saved image is empty(0 bytes).

Comment: Is the url a protected URL? I'm not able to access this image via the URL directly. This might explain why file is of 0 KBs.

Comment: add some implicit wait and try. We can also use driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/google.png')

Comment: @demouser123 No, its not. Are you opening it in your browser ?

Comment: @santhoshkumar driver.get_screenshot_as_file is having same problem.

Comment: Can you add some implicit wait and some sleep and try? Is the screenshot working for other sites?

Answer (score 1):

My answer cannot solve your current issue, but if you want just to save picture you can avoid using `selenium` and simply use below piece of code:

```
import urllib

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://media.santabanta.com/medium1/cricket/trent%20boult/trent-boult-0a.jpg", 'path/to/im1.jpg')
```

*P.S. In Python 2.X `urllib.urlretrieve()` should be used instead of `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`*

Comment: Although this method worked for me, but I dont know whether I should accept this answer since the question is about Selenium